# Webserver PHP log for Curl actions

Tags: apache-2.2

I have a PHP script that uses Curl to call another server via SSL. Is it possible to see the contents of the POST action in any log on the server where the script is running?  The server is a Apache2 running on (I think) Centros.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's happening from PHP, generally not. A problem may cause PHP to spew an error, which could end up in apache's error log. Accessing an https URL from the script makes no appreciable difference.